# Grouping Excel Value to a Particular Row value

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a Excel Sheet Like

[image]

```
I want output values as 
1 - 10
2 - 23
3 - 13
4 - 29
```

Using Collections , I know I have to Collections Hashmap but i am able to figure out .

My code so far

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String excelFilePath = "C:\\Users\\SINGH\\Desktop\\test.xlsx";
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));

    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
    ArrayList<Integer> amount = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Row nextRow = iterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                //System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                amount.add((int) cell.getNumericCellValue());

            }


            System.out.print(" - ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    workbook.close();
    inputStream.close();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a map to store both account id and corresponding amount. And, while iterating through excel sheet, if a value already exists then, we can add the existing value into that and store it again. Below is the example code:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> accounts = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
int accountId = //read account id from excel
int amount = //read amount from excel
//If entry already exists in map then, add the new value to existing value
if(accounts.containsKey(accountId)){
    amount += accounts.get(accountId);
}
//set the value in map, this will replace the existing value
accounts.put(accountId, amount);
```

***update*** As asked in comments, alternate solution using Pojo
We can create a Dto class like the one below:

```
class AccountDto{
    private int accountId;
    private int amount;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And then, we can use a list to store Dto objects. We also need to method to check whether the dto is already exists in the list (using accountId), if yes then we can just add the amount. Below is the pseido code:

```
List<AccountDto> accounts = new ArrayList<AccountDto>();
int accountId = //read account id from excel
int amount = //read amount from excel

AccountDto accountDto = findById(accountId, accounts);
//Check whether account exists in the list
if(null == accountDto){
    //If not then add a new object
    accountDto = new AccountDto(accountId, amount);
}else{
   //If yes then, add the amount
    accountDto.setAmount(accountDto.getAmount() + amount);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem here is that i cannot read both the values independently like for column header account and column header amount .
It is stored in a row object and then i am iterating througj it this is the issue .if you see how i print those values, and also how will i know if the amount exists for the account.

Comment: You can check column index of a cell to determine which value you are reading (e.g. if column index is 0 then it must be accountId, if column index is 1 then it must be amount). You can use `getColumnIndex()` to get the index of column. Once you are finished reading all the cells for a row (after while loop that iterates cells), you can place my logic to put the values inside map.

Comment: I was wondering if u could use pojo classes in this, i will try your idea but can we use pojo

Comment: We can obviously use pojo classes. However, if we store class objects into a list then we need to write the methods to let's say, return a particular object from the list that corresponds to provided accountId. Map already has that and hence, makes our task easier :)

Comment: Can you suggest a example i am new to it

Comment: Added alternate solution in the answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother you further darshan But how can we display only the rows which has cells which are blank

Comment: I know but if I have to display the the row in which the cell value is Null RNA cell value is Null and only displayed that rows suppose there are 10 rose and to rose container cell that has blank or null value so how do you display this to rows

Comment: Sorry, unable to understand the behavior. Can you add an example into the question? Actually, it is better to ask the new question as my answer works for examples mentioned in this question.